# constructing absolute path with os.path.join()

Tags: python, path, absolute-path

I'd like to construct an absolute path in python, while at the same time staying fairly oblivious of things like path-separator.

**edit0:** for instance there is a directory on the root of my filesystem `/etc/init.d` (or `C:\etc\init.d` on w32), and I want to construct this only from the elements `etc` and `init.d` (on w32, I probably also need a disk-ID, like `C:`)

In order to not having to worry about path-separators, `os.join.path()` is obviously the tool of choice. But it seems that this will only ever create *relative* paths:

```
 print("MYPATH: %s" % (os.path.join('etc', 'init.d'),)
 MYPATH: etc/init.d
```

Adding a dummy first-element (e.g. `''`) doesn't help anything:

```
 print("MYPATH: %s" % (os.path.join('', 'etc', 'init.d'),)
 MYPATH: etc/init.d
```

Making the first element absolute obviously helps, but this kind of defeats the idea of using `os.path.join()`

```
 print("MYPATH: %s" % (os.path.join('/etc', 'init.d'),)
 MYPATH: /etc/init.d
```

**edit1:** using `os.path.abspath()` will only try to convert a relative path into an absolute path.
e.g. consider running the following in the working directory `/home/foo`:

```
 print("MYPATH: %s" % (os.path.abspath(os.path.join('etc', 'init.d')),)
 MYPATH: /home/foo/etc/init.d
```

So, what is the standard cross-platform way to "root" a path?

```
 root = ??? # <--
 print("MYPATH: %s" % (os.path.join(root, 'etc', 'init.d'),)
 MYPATH: /etc/init.d
```

**edit2:** the question really boils down to: since the leading slash in `/etc/init.d` makes this path an absolute path, is there a way to construct this leading slash programmatically?
(I do not want to make assumptions that a leading slash indicates an absolute path)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm reading your question correctly, but could you simply: `os.path.abspath('python.exe')` which on my windows machine returns `'C:\\Python27\\python.exe'`

Comment: i've updated the question to (hopefully) clarify what i want.

Comment: btw, relevant near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041525/a-system-independent-way-using-python-to-get-the-root-directory-drive-on-which-p

Comment: None of these answers work for me. How can I join `root_dir="C:/Users/folder"` with `filename="data/file1.txt"` to get an absolute path? In not-windows it's easy with just `os.path.join(root_dir, filename)`, but I can't find a solution in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the solution i came up with, is to construct the root of the filesystem by following a given file to it's root:

```
def getRoot(file=None):
  if file is None:
      file='.'
  me=os.path.abspath(file)
  drive,path=os.path.splitdrive(me)
  while 1:
    path,folder=os.path.split(path)
    if not folder:
       break
  return drive+path

 os.path.join(getRoot(), 'etc', 'init.d')
```

Comment: could even be simpler: 

drive,path=os.path.splitdrive(me)
if not drive:
return os.path.split(path)[0]
else:
return drive

Comment: hmm, i'm sure that my solution is not the most pythonic way; but your solution will return `/foo/bar/baz` if the file evaulates to `/foo/bar/baz` (basically the problem you mentioned for Ansuman's answer)

Comment: darn it, you're right. got misled by another answer on SO >.<

Comment: I find this interesting but I am somewhat puzzled on the reason why it is still the accepted answer.

Answer (score 97):

Using `os.sep` as root worked for me:

```
path.join(os.sep, 'python', 'bin')
```

Linux: `/python/bin`

Windows: `\python\bin`

Adding `path.abspath()` to the mix will give you drive letters on Windows as well and is still compatible with Linux:

```
path.abspath(path.join(os.sep, 'python', 'bin'))
```

Linux: `/python/bin`

Windows: `C:\python\bin`

Comment: Seems to work on Linux and Win, so +1. But *feels* wrong. Might break on some other obscure system, but I can think of none. Still feels like python should give us an explicit way to do that. This depends on absolute paths starting with the path-separator.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `os.path.normpath`. Here's what I get on Windows:

```
>>> os.path.normpath("/etc/init.d")
'\\etc\\init.d'
```

I'm not sure exactly what the right thing to do with the drive prefix is, but I think leaving it off means something like "keep using the drive I'm on now," which is probably what you want. Maybe someone more familiar with Windows can clarify?

Comment: this is the right answer, let python do the work of figuring out which platform you're on

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, yet this uses a fully qualified path and NOT `os.path.join()`.  While it is useful to know, it does not qualify as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

So you can do a check for running os
by sys.platfrom

on windows

```
>>> sys.platform
'win32'
```

on linux

```
>>> sys.platform
'linux2'
```

then

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    ROOT = os.path.splitdrive(os.path.abspath('.'))[0]
elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
    ROOT = os.sep
```

Please note that 'linux2' may not cover all linux distros

Comment: no, i really want the ROOT of my filesystem (regardless where the python modules are located). `os.path.abspath('foo')` will return (e.g.) `/home/me/foo` (if i run it within `/home/me`) while i really need `/foo` (or `C:\\foo`)

Comment: i've updated the question to clarify why `os.path.abspath()` does not seem to help me.

Comment: If you want to have a ROOT which is not based on file and same ROOT for all files in a specific project. Than you can store the ROOT (a string value) in a config file or you can define a ROOT by hardcoded values in all the file. I have added this in my answer.

Comment: the question is: what makes `/etc` an absolute path? (obviously the `/` prefix, but is there a programmatic way to get this suffix?)

Comment: OK. I think I got it. There is os.path.splitdrive() which returns you the drive os.path.splitdrive(os.path.abspath('.')) but on linux it will not return you the root ie. '/'

Comment: doesn't work for if you're deeper in a directory tree, e.g.:
In [3]: os.path.split(os.path.abspath('.'))
Out[3]: ('/home', 'username')

Comment: hmm, this will give me nothing on osx and gnu/hurd; with "cross-platform" i had "not having to care about the platform" in mind, not "discussing each platform manually"

Answer (score -1):

you could try with `os.path.splitdrive` to get the name of your drive/filesystem, then join this with your `foo` string.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive

something like (untested!)

```
(drive, tail) = os.path.splitdrive(os.getcwd())
os.path.join(drive, 'foo')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: doesn't work on linux - drive gets set to '' and joining with that doesn't give a rooted path