# String concatenation takes place on the next line in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-concatenation

Python has a simple concatenation using the `+` operator. But I am observing something unusual.

I tried :

```
final_path = '/home/user/' + path + '/output'
```

Where `path` is a staring variable I want to concatenate.

```
print final_path
```

gives me:

```
/home/user/path
/output
```

Instead of `/home/user/path/output`

Why is going to the next line.
Is the forward slash causing the issue.
I tried using the escape character as well. but It does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [constructing absolute path with os.path.join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429044/constructing-absolute-path-with-os-path-join)

Comment: tl;dr `os.path.join(os.sep, 'home', 'user', path, 'output')`

Comment: If you're getting `path` from a file, that's your problem. Each line in the file includes the newline character. Just use `path.strip()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of your code, it may be the variable `path` that is the problem. Check to see if `path` has a new line at the end. Escape characters start with a backslash `\` and not a forward slash `/`.

Comment: I had another variable and there was a newline char "hidden", so your answer got me right, time saver!

Answer (score 1):

As victor said, your path variable has '\n' added at the end implicitly, so you can do such a trick to overcome the problem:

```
final_path = '/home/user/' + path.strip('\n') + '/output'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it depends on which string is contained in the variable path. If it ends with a carriage return ('\n'), this could explain why string variable final_path is printed on 2 lines.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when path is from another file for example a .txt where you are importing the data. I solved this by adding path.strip() which removes whitespaces before the str and after for the newline which is being generated. Just add .strip() to your variable.