# FileNotFoundError with leading slash issue on AWS Lambda with Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My development environment is a Windows machine. When trying to download a file from S3 locally it works no problem. When I load the function to Lambda, however, I receive a `FileNotFoundError` error which is caused by the Lambda requiring a leading slash in the file key.

This works locally, but does not on Lambda...

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
new_file_key = os.path.join('tmp', file_name)
s3.Bucket('bucketname').download_file(file_key, new_file_key)
```

This works on Lambda, but not locally...

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
new_file_key = os.path.join('/tmp', file_name)
s3.Bucket('bucketname').download_file(file_key, new_file_key)
```

What's the simplest way to handle this?

Comment: Where is the value of `file_name` coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want the file to be downloaded to

- `C:\tmp` on windows
- `/tmp` on your lambda container (linux)

Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080468/242311) as a reference, the following should behave in a platform-agnostic manner:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
new_file_key = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.sep, 'tmp', file_name))
s3.Bucket('bucketname').download_file(file_key, new_file_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

On MS Windows `os.path.join` uses `\` which doesn't work with s3 paths

The Lambda is running on a Linux host so `os.path.join` is `/` which s3 likes

To fix it hardwire the join to use `/`

```
new_file_key = '/'.join(['/tmp', file_name])
```