# Getting full path to a file in Python is omitting one directory

Tags: python, file, path

I'm aware that I can do either of the two to get the full path to a file:

```
>>> import os
>>> import pathlib
>>> path1 = str(pathlib.Path('filename').parent.absolute())
>>> path2 = os.path.abspath('filename')
```

The current structure of the absolute path to `filename` is `/home/user/directory/filename`. However, when I print the two variables `path1` and `path2` I only get `/home/user/filename` with the `directory` omitted.

Would anybody know why this happens, and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You are providing a string `filename`. You could call this string anything and it would still return a path even to a filename that doesn't exist. There is no connection between the string `filename` and the path `/home/user/directory/filename`. To get the path of the python file the script is running in you do `os.path.abspath(__file__)`

Comment: Hmm is there no other way, or a way to use the `__file__` variable to get the specific path to another file? The reason why I'm doing `filename` as a string is because there's a specific file that I'm planning on using with `subprocess.call` to run in the script.

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429044/constructing-absolute-path-with-os-path-join

Comment: why can't you just do `Path('/home/user/directory')` and then join whatever file name you need to that?

Comment: Well I'm trying to make my code a bit flexible for others to possibly use as they may have the specific file in other locations. I thought it'd be convenient for the script to automatically find the location with minimum intervention on the user's end.