# Is there a Python function to determine the root directory with os module?

Tags: python, python-os

I recently started learning Python language and the textbook I have, while presenting the `os` module, explained how to use the `os.name` attribute in order to determine the root directory of the operative system - so, a hardcoded solution based on the `if-elif-else` construct.
Just for the sake of practising and start to get keen on this language, I tried to generalise this solution.

I used the `os.path.split()` function, knowing that splitting the root directory `root_dir` returns the tuple `(root_dir, '')`, where the first element is the root directory and the second is the empty string.
Here, I used a support variable `my_tuple`, initialised to `(os.getcwd(), None)`, which is updated via the use of `split()` function in a `while` loop until its second element is `''`.

```
my_tuple = (os.getcwd(), None)
while my_tuple[1] != '':
    my_tuple = os.path.split(my_tuple[0])
root_dir = my_tuple[0]
```

Clearly, this is a clumsy solution, for which reason I was wondering if there's a cleaner - and a more Pythonic - way to achieve the goal.
For example, if one imports the `pathlib` module, they may use the `PurePath.root` attribute, easy peasy.

Is something similar possible with `os` module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041525/a-system-independent-way-using-python-to-get-the-root-directory-drive-on-which-p describes a few functions which should help.

Comment: @PavelShishpor exaxtly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment to your post contains the solution you're asking for, but I'll write it here for completeness. With the `os`-module, you can use

```
path = os.getcwd()
root = os.path.splitdrive(path)[0]
```

to have the variable `root` contain what you're after.